# how to create all combinations of two elements using foreach in TCL

Tags: arrays, list, foreach, tcl, combinations

I want to create all combinations of 2 like this but doesnt seem to work .

Am I missing something here ?

```
 foreach swt "$Agg1 $Agg2" {

      foreach acc "$Acc1 $Acc2 $Acc3" {

      Function (swt acc) {
      } 
    }
 }
```

I want all combinations like Agg1 Acc1 , Agg1 Acc2 , Agg1 Acc3 , Agg2 Acc1 , Agg2 Acc2 , Agg2 Acc3  to be passed to the function .

But It doesnt seem to work with the above code . The only other way i can think of is creating 6 code blocks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're interpolating variables that don't (presumably) yet exist. Take out the dollar signs.

```
foreach swt "Agg1 Agg2" {
    foreach acc "Acc1 Acc2 Acc3" {
        puts "$swt $acc"
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend using curly braces there, although you can use quotes.

```
foreach swt {Agg1 Agg2} {
    foreach acc {Acc1 Acc2 Acc3} {
        puts "$swt $acc"
    }
}
```